# Pure python library to read and write jpeg format

Tags: python, jpeg

guys!
I'm looking for pure python implementation of jpeg writing (reading will be nice, but not necessary) library.
I've founded only TonyJPEG library port at http://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2004-November/003055.html
But the problem is this library doesn't support writing.

Any ideas?

**UPD:** I need to modify jpeg algorithm (starting from DCT) to make working prototype.

**UPD2:** The best decision for me was to port Jpeg library from the another language. I've chosen TonyJPEG library, because It's simplier than [libJPEG](http://www.ijg.org/files/).
If you need effective low-level access to JPEG in Python, the best choice is to port something like libJPEG or try to understand how tools like PIL works.

Comment: Have you *seen* the JPEG source code? That's really not something you want to port...

Comment: It might be helpful to put in why pure python is a requirement instead of using the existing compiled libraries which support this.

Comment: @ignacio-vazquez-abrams What do you mean saying "JPEG source code"? If you're talking about deprecated JPEG module, I can say that it is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: @ignacio-vazquez-abrams Thanks, but it's too comprehensive for my purposes. I've ported Part from TonyJPEG library (It looks more readable) and everything works for me.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any libraries written in 100% python, however if you just need the library to work in python, then use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/). It supports reading and writing many different imaging formats, including JPEG. Realistically, it should do everything you need it to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want fairly low level access, you can use [`libjpeg`](http://freshmeat.net/projects/libjpeg/) through [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html).
(NB: you didn't specify your working environment)