# Reading jpeg in python on a mac

Tags: python, jpeg

I need to read jpeg images in a python program running on a mac. The obvious answer would be to install PIL, but I have two problems with that.

On the one hand, it seems an overkill, since I don't quite need all the image processing capabilities. On top of that, PIL is quite messy and I like to keep my systems clean.

On the other hand, I haven't found a binary installation of PIL for mac, and I don't have gcc installed. I don't want to install gcc (and all the mess that comes with it) for the same clean-system principle.

Does anybody know a *simple* python library that doesn't have to be compiled and that will allow me to read jpeg images in a python program?

Thanks

Comment: You could install PIL in virtual environment, that way you'll keep you system clean.

Comment: If you don't want to compile, and there are no binaries, you'd need a pure Python JPEG library. [That doesn't seem to exist.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993836/pure-python-library-to-read-and-write-jpeg-format)